# acmart package: forcing certain number of authors into the first row

Tags: author, acmart

Is there a way to force a certain number of authors per row in [acmart](https://github.com/borisveytsman/acmart)? I am aware there is this command: `\settopmatter{authorsperrow=4}`; however, I would like to force the first row to only contain 2 authors, then the rest to contain 3.

For example, I currently have this:
[image]

And when I add a "blank" author to force the first line to two authors, I get:
[image]

Is there a way to better center that first row to avoid a large gap? Or to just force two authors into that first line?

For context, here is the sample latex doc to generate the second image:

```
\documentclass[sigconf,screen]{acmart}
\begin{document}

\title[Sample Title]{Sample Title}

\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}


%%Block to force only two authors on first line
\author{~}
\affiliation{%
\institution{~}
\state{~}
\country{~}
}
 
\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}
\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}

\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}

\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}

\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}

\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}

\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}

\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}

\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}

\author{Jane Doe}
\orcid{xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx}
\affiliation{%
  \institution{Institution}
  \state{State}
  \country{USA}
}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Could you edit into your question the code you are using (the bare minimum packages and commands) please, it makes it a lot easier to help and sometimes it is the only way to help

Comment: Thanks! Updated.